# How to create an empty KeyEvent and SetKeyCode(keyCode) in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In my project, I'm trying to receive a `dataInputStream` which is `readInt()` from another computer that sends `writeInt(e.getKeyCode())` to this computer, but when I receives the `keyCode`, how do I put it into a `KeyEvent` object?

**Here's a part of my coding:**

```
KeyEvent enemyKey;
try{
  key = inputFromClient.readInt();
  if(key!=0) {
    enemyKey.setKeyCode(key);
    player2.keyPressed(enemyKey);
  }
}catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println(ex);
}
```

By executing the code above, I get NullPointerException because `KeyEvent` enemyKey is `null`.
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: you haven't initialized `KeyEvent enemyKey`

Comment: instead of 0 put there Null..

Comment: @Maneti Vinay, the "key" is actually an INT value I receive from DataInputStream with the readInt() function, and you can't compare int with NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `KeyEvent enemyKey;` You can initialize it with this constructor

```
public KeyEvent(Component source,
    int id,
    long when,
    int modifiers,
    int keyCode,
    char keyChar)
```

> **source** - The Component that originated the event
>
> **id** - An integer indicating the type of event. For information on allowable values, see the class description for KeyEvent
>
> **when** - A long integer that specifies the time the event occurred. Passing negative or zero value is not recommended
>
> **modifiers** - The modifier keys down during event (shift, ctrl, alt, meta). Passing negative value is not recommended. Zero value means that no modifiers were passed. Use either an extended _DOWN_MASK or old _MASK modifiers, however do not mix models in the one event. The extended modifiers are preferred for using
>
> **keyCode** - The integer code for an actual key, or VK_UNDEFINED (for a key-typed event)
>
> **keyChar** - The Unicode character generated by this event, or CHAR_UNDEFINED (for key-pressed and key-released events which do not map to a valid Unicode character)

See [KeyEvent javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KeyEvent%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20long,%20int,%20int%29) for more information on values you can pass to the constructor

Also, take a look at [Javabeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/)

Comment: Can I just initialize it with KeyEvent enemyKey = new KeyEvent(this, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'a'); ?

Comment: As this KeyEvent is not generated by using KeyListener, is there any way to declare a KeyEvent object without using KeyListener?

Comment: An event is useless without a listener listening for it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe I can shed some light as to how you can go about it.

Comment: I am trying to create a small 1v1 fighting Java game with DataInputStream and DataOutputStream, I'd like to retrieve the key input of the opponent and use it as a KeyEvent so I can identify the moves that my opponent used.

I thought of passing the whole KeyEvent as an object by using DataOutputStream.writeObject(keyEvent) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this tutorial on [writing javabeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/)

Comment: I managed to writeObject(KeyEvent) and the problem is solved, thanks man.